# null value is not recognized in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller $scope.test is set by the value from server. If value from server is null, line 1 below prints null but it goes into else condition, i have tried $scope.test != null, $scope.test !== null but still it does not recognize null/

```
alert($scope.test) //line 1 prints null
  if(!$scope.test) {
                alert("$scope.test is null " + $scope.test);
            }
            else{
                alert("test not all"); // prints test not null
    }
```

Comment: Are you check this after the callback from the server? You might need to post more code...

Comment: Hm, may it be the value is `"null"` and not `null`?

Comment: yes, if the alert gives a popup with "null" written on it, then the server returns a string

Answer (score 0):

try 
     if($scope.test!='null') 
Your server is probably returning a string, meaning a null value will be returned  as 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `typeof $scope.test` if it returning object or string "It should return object in your case" probably u r getting "null" of type string that's why it is not recognize